# How to implement pivot data in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have created following models in ASP.NET MVC. Now I have to send products data by API or JSON format.

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<ProductAttribute> ProductAttributes { get; set; }
}

public class ProductAttribute
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; } //foreign key
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Currently data comes in this way after converting into JSON.
[image]

But I want to convert it into Pivot view, something like this.

[image]

How can I do this by using Entity Framework or LINQ ? Thanks

Comment: Is that output already fixed or can it be modified?

Comment: No, its not fixed. It created it manually :)

Answer (score 2):

I would change the output to

```
[
    {
        "Id": 21098,
        "Name": "12 Port Fast USB Charging Station for iPad, iPhone",
        "Attributes":{
            "Size": "Large",
            "Length": "Short"
        }
    }
]
```

The response class will look like

```
public class ProductResponse
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string,string> Attributes { get; set; }
}
```

and you can create the collection from your query

```
IList<ProductResponse> response = myContext.Set<Product>()
    .Include( e => e.ProductAttributes )

    .Where( e => e.Id == 21098 )

    .Select( e => new ProductResponse {
        Id = e.Id,
        Name = e.Name,
        Attributes = e.ProductAttributes.ToDictionary( e => e.Key, e => e.Value ),
    } )
    .ToList();
```

and return that collection

Comment: But it will produce same output as I have done. I want to get pivot view, I mean Key, Value data into column.

Comment: Hmmm, I asked before my answer if the output is fixed or if a modification is possible.

Comment: And it does **not** produce the same output as you have done

Comment: Sorry, currently I dont have required output.